# IDir '193.174.193.64' does not match to 'vpngw.fh-kempten.de

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, strongswan, xl2tpd

I am trying to configure my client using VPN (strongswan) to access the remote server whose DNS is
vpngw.fh-kempten.de

Details of my remote VPN Server are:
Authentication Method = Mutual +XAuth
PSK =****

**Phase 1**
Exchange Type = aggressive
DH exchange = group2
Cipher Algorithm = 3ds
Hash Algorithm = md5
Key life time limit = 28800secs

**Phase 2**
Tensform Algorithm = esp-3des
HMAC Algorithm = md5
PFC exchange = Auto
compress Algorithm = disabled
Key life time limit = 28800secs

**General**

Host Name or IP = vpngw.fh-kempten.de
port = 500
Auto configuration = IKE conf. pull
MTU = 1400
Adapter mode = use a virtual adapter and assigned address

**Client**
firewall options
NAT traversal = enable
NAT traversal port = 4500
Keep alive packet rate = 15s
IKE fragmentation = enable
Maximum packet siye = 540 bytes

### This is all info I have related to my VPN Server which is a remote server.

Using the command `sudo ipsec up ikev1-psk-xauth`, I try to run my client VPN. I get the following error in my raspberry pi

```
initiating Aggressive Mode IKE_SA ikev1-psk-xauth[1] to 193.174.193.64
generating AGGRESSIVE request 0 [ SA KE No ID V V V V V ]
sending packet: from 192.168.60.96[500] to 193.174.193.64[500] (363 bytes)
received packet: from 193.174.193.64[500] to 192.168.60.96[500] (404 bytes)
parsed AGGRESSIVE response 0 [ SA KE No ID HASH V V V NAT-D NAT-D V V ]
received Cisco Unity vendor ID
received XAuth vendor ID
received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
received unknown vendor ID: 1f:07:f7:0e:aa:65:14:d3:b0:fa:96:54:2a:50:01:00
IDir '193.174.193.64' does not match to 'vpngw.fh-kempten.de'
generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 304912695 [ N(INVAL_ID) ]
sending packet: from 192.168.60.96[500] to 193.174.193.64[500] (56 bytes)
establishing connection 'ikev1-psk-xauth' failed
```

Following is my ipsec.conf file

```
config setup
conn ikev1-psk-xauth
ikelifetime=28800s
keylife=20m
rekeymargin=3m
keyingtries=1
keyexchange=ikev1
authby=secret
ike = 3des-md5-modp1024!
esp = 3des-md5-modp1024!
modeconfig = pull
aggressive = yes
fragmentation=yes
#keyexchange = ikev2
authby = secret
type = transport
leftauth = psk
leftauth2 = xauth
leftprotoport=17/1701
rightprotoport=17/1701
right = vpngw.fh-kempten.de
rightauth = psk
rightauth2 = xauth
auto = add
```

My motivation is to access the shared drives which are present on the remote VPN server.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The remote identity the server returns does not match your configuration (the identities default to the IP addresses). Try configuring `rightid = vpngw.fh-kempten.de` and you might have to configure `leftid` to the group name (Cisco lingo), which you have to determine somehow.

For your information, using Aggressive Mode with XAauth/PSK is [inherently unsafe](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/FAQ#Aggressive-Mode) and the algorithm selection is from a different era (so is the use of L2TP actually), so you might want to complain to the admins of your university for providing such a crappy VPN.

Comment: After yout possible recommendation. I changed my config file and commenting agressive gives me the following when I run 
          `sudo ipsec up  ikev1-psk-xauth`

Comment: `parsed TRANSACTION request 36532437 [ HASH CPS(X_STATUS) ]
no XAuth method found
`

Comment: Sounds like the _xauth-generic_ plugin is not loaded. See [here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/FAQ#Plugin-is-missing).

Comment: I have tried to install and use ** xauth-generic **  plugin but when I try to install using this command 
<!-- sudo apt-get install strongswan strongswan-plugin-xauth-generic--> 
, it gives me the following lines
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package strongswan-plugin-xauth-generic

Comment: Individual packages for plugins were only available on older Ubuntu releases. On newer ones the plugin is in the _libcharon-standard-plugins_ package.

Comment: Thanks, so to conclude this, when I checked the status of my ipsec using  ´sudo nano ipsec statusall´ , I can see that the xauth-generic plugin is there. :)